# How to focus one button by default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having trouble with 2 buttons that each toggles different "div" elements. I want to focus "button 1" by default. How do I do that? Autofocus is not working. 
 Here's the HTML code

```
<div class="filter">
     <button class="filter-btn active" data-target="#block-1" autofocus>1</button>
     <button class="filter-btn" data-target="#block-2">2</button>
 </div>
```

Here's the JS code

```
let $blocks = $(".block-card");

$(".filter-btn").on("click", (e) => {
  let $btn = $(e.target).addClass("active");
  $btn.siblings().removeClass("active");

  let selector = $btn.data("target");
  $blocks.removeClass("active").filter(selector).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: to test if `autofocus` works or not, try put this `button:focus{ background-color: red !important; }` in global css and reload the page. if the background of your button with `autofocus` turns red, that means `autofocus` is working.

Comment: I have a css code that works when I click them. It's just it's not focusing automatically when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `autofocus` is not working due to browser behavior or styling of other elements, you can still use Javascript to set focus.

Example:

```
document.querySelector(".filter-btn.active").focus({focusVisible: true});
```

`{focusVisible: true}` is optional here and it forces browser to make the focus visible.

There is a jQuery equivalent, but it seems that it does not take the optional config.

Example:

```
$(".filter-btn.active").focus();
```

Some CSS can be added to making testing easier.

Example:

```
button:focus {
  color: crimson;
}

button:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

When running the following example, note that the first button should be focused.

Full example: **(run it in live with button below)**

```js
document.querySelector(".filter-btn.active").focus({focusVisible: true});
```

```css
button:focus{ color: crimson }

button:focus-visible {
    outline: 2px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
     <button class="filter-btn active" data-target="#block-1">1</button>
     <button class="filter-btn" data-target="#block-2">2</button>
 </div>
```

Hope this will help!